# Adding binding to power point content

Tags: office365, office-js

Is it possible to add binding to power point and set and get content on binding and get all the binding like getAllsync in power point?Please suggest..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binding concept is not supported in PPT, unfortunately. Please make sure to add this request to our user voice channel. thanks!.
https://officespdev.uservoice.com/

Comment: Thanks Juan..sure I will add to user voice